# How to hide days in UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, swift3, uidatepicker

How to hide days in `UIDatePicker` and add Done button in the `UIDatePicker`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  PickerViewApp
//  Created by Apple on 16/06/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Valuesol. All rights reserved.
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController ,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet var textField:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var datePickerView:UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var CancleButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet var ToolBar:UIToolbar!
    var pickerDaysmonth = [["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"],["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]];
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.datePickerView.delegate = self
        self.datePickerView.dataSource = self
    }
    @IBAction func canclebtntapped() {
        self.datePickerView.isHidden = true
        self.ToolBar.isHidden = true
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return self.pickerDaysmonth[component].count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return self.pickerDaysmonth[component][row]
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let days =  pickerDaysmonth[0][pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        let month = pickerDaysmonth[1][pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
        textField.text =   days + " " + month
    }
}
```

Try this Code 
It's Working

[image]

Comment: how to manage 29 Feb/ 30 Feb / 31 Feb / 31 April / 31 June / 31 Sep / 31 Nov

Comment: You can implement set of conditions in pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) which will update data source referring to days.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do it using `UIDatePicker`, you've to use the custom library or your own created custom view.

Use this Library [MonthYearPickerView-Swift](https://github.com/bendodson/MonthYearPickerView-Swift):

Add `MonthYearPickerView.swift` file to your project and use:

```
let monthYearPickerView = MonthYearPickerView()
monthlyPickerView.onDateSelected = { (month: Int, year: Int) in
    let string = String(format: "%02d/%d", month, year)
    NSLog(string) // should show something like 05/2015
}
monthYearPickerView.frame = CGRect(frame)
view.addSubview(monthYearPickerView)
```

Note: Add your own toolbar on top of PickerView.

Output:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: @ImadAli how to print by default month year which comes on launch on first time

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to totally eliminate dates from the picker's wheel. You can implement your own datepicker as a UIPickerView or use any-other library.

You can easy show month & year in your own custom picker.12 - months,get 50 years from current year.